# determine whether two arrays are permutation of each other by using recursion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, permutation

I have some difficulties in writing a code which determines whether two unsorted arrays are permutation of each other , by using recursion.
I know how to determine it by non-recursive code, using sorts - but I dont know how to do it by using recursion.

So far, I cant get any real idea...

```
int CheckPermutation(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size) {
    if (size == 0) 
        return 1;
    if (size == 1)   
       return (arr1[0] > arr2[0]);
}
```

that's what I have tried, I find it difficult to continue from that point

Comment: You can sort them using recursion.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is it supposed to be a recursion exercise? Otherwise you can keep it simple by checking that the frequency of each character in arrayA appearing in arrayB, is the same as the frequency of each character in arrayB appearing in arrayA.

Comment: I have just edited my question and added what I have tried...

Comment: Yeah and I find it hard to understand why you have now trashed the code you posted, which I formatted. Some of it has gone missing.

Comment: I have just edited it again...sorry...

Comment: Are the arrays allowed to be modified?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation for comparing 2 unsorted arrays without modifying them that uses recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// count occurrences of value in an array using recursion
int rcount(int value, const int *a, int size) {
    return size == 0 ? 0 : (value == *a) + rcount(value, a + 1, size - 1);
}

// check if all entries in a have the same number of occurrences in a and b
int check_perm(const int *a, const int *b, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (rcount(a[i], a, size) != rcount(a[i], b, size))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, };
    int b[] = { 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, };
    int c[] = { 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 6, 6, };

    if (check_perm(a, b, sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)))
        printf("arrays a and b match\n");

    if (!check_perm(a, c, sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)))
        printf("arrays a and c do not match\n");

    if (!check_perm(b, c, sizeof(b) / sizeof(*b)))
        printf("arrays b and c do not match\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a solution with a single recursive function. Both arrays are potentially modified.  If indeed `check_perm()` returns non zero, both arrays will have been sorted:

```
int check_perm(const int *a, const int *b, int size) {
    if (size > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (a[0] > a[i]) {
                int temp = a[0];
                a[0] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
            }
            if (b[0] > b[i]) {
                int temp = b[0];
                b[0] = b[i];
                b[i] = temp;
            }
        }
        return (a[0] == b[0]) && check_perm(a + 1, b + 1, size - 1);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `rcount` uses recursion because it is mandated, it would be more idiomatic in C to use a simple `for` loop.

Comment: By the way, how about using swap? Can it help in solving this issue by another method?

Comment: @GalI: i am not sure what you mean by `swao()`, there is no standard function for swapping values.  Furthermore, I do not change the arrays.  If you can change the arrays, sort them with a recursive algorithm such as `mergesort` and compare them.

Comment: I know mergesort. How should I writing a recursive code using mergesort and comparison of two arrays?

Comment: I'm glad if someone could help me in writing this recursive code (using mergesort and comparison).

Comment: @GalI: `mergesort()` itself uses recursion. Once the arrays are sorted, you can compare them with a simple loop.

Comment: I know, but the function itself must be recursive...I assume that the comparison must be recursive too...

Comment: @GalI: I updated the answer with a simpler recursive function.